# How do I declare custom JButtons with composition and add action listeners to them?

Tags: java

I am currently in the process of changing my extended buttons to making them use composition and in the process of turning my MouseListeners to action listeners. I will need to know when it is clicked and isRollover(); I'm new to GUI and help is appreciated. How do I declare the buttons correctly in the different class? Where do I add the actionListeners in the EmptySpace class?

```
public class EmptySpace{

  private JButton button;
  protected int x; 
  protected int y;
  protected String name;

  public EmptySpace(String text, int x, int y){
    this.name = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    button = new JButton(text);

  }

  public String toString(){
      return "Name: " + name + " Xcoords: " + x + " Ycoords: " + y;

  }

  public JButton getButton(){
      return button;

  }
}
```

different class

```
   for (int i = 0; i < lengthx*lengthy; i++) {
        if(i<lengthx){
            x = i+1;
        }else x = i % lengthx+1;
        if(i<lengthx){
            y=1;
        }else y = i/lengthx+1;

        String xString = Integer.toString(x);
        String yString = Methods.getChar(y);



      buttons[x-1][y-1] = new EmptySpace(xString+yString,x,y);
      buttons[x-1][y-1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25)); //error
      buttons[x-1][y-1].setBackground(Color.WHITE); //error
      buttons[x-1][y-1].setText(""); //error
      buttons[x-1][y-1].setToolTipText(xString+yString); //error

      pane.add(buttons[x-1][y-1]); //error
```

Comment: What is the type of the buttons? You are calling JButton methods on what appears to be an array of type EmptySpace. Since button has private access in your class you need to use the getButton method then those methods.

Comment: I updated the code to show the loop, my apologies.

Comment: If you want customized JButtons, perhaps you should extend the JButton class, not encapsulate its instance? Usually people make the opposite mistake: use inheritance when they should encapsulate, but this seems one of the rare cases when it's the other way around.

Comment: I put a question up last night about how to access get methods across a hierarchy of buttons (I have two types of buttons) and everyone said I should use composition and replace the mouse listeners with action listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add action listeners to your buttons instead of mouse listeners then first make sure that you have imported java.awt.event
Add an actionlistener to your button like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new myButtonListener());
```

Then create a inner class with the name of your action listener like this:

```
public class myButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
    //do what you want your button to do
   }
}
```

Make sure that the function is always called action performed and always has an actionEvent as the parameter.